# While Importing the Ng2-charts Module into the Angular12

Tags: angular, typescript

This likely means that the library (ng2-charts) which declares ThemeService has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li4YP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your module is not yet loaded by the Angular Server because you probably installed it without disconnecting it. In order to make it work you need to restart your server (ctrl + c on console) so the server loads the module that you just installed.

Comment: Restarted the Server But Same seems to be Appeared.

Comment: Maybe delete node_modules and try npm i?

Comment: Deleted the Node modules and Installed NPM, Same Errors Exists

Comment: If you have time, try to make a new project and install the ng2-chart, but it seems there are compatibility errors